# Query working in Oracle DB but not in HQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to write a simple query where I am just subtracting two timestamps from DB.

```
select ticket_status, 
       count(ticket_status), 
       trunc (to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')-to_date('2004/12/12 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')) as days 
from ITS_TICKET_MASTER 
group by ticket_status, 
trunc (to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')-to_date('2004/12/12 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM'))
```

This query is giving me the result I want

But when I am trying the same query in HQL then it is giving me error.

> QueryImpl(select ticketStatus, count(ticketStatus), trunc
>   (to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI
>   PM')-to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')) as days
>   from WebTicket group by ticketStatus, trunc (to_date('2004/12/14 4:29
>   PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')-to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD
>   HH:MI PM'))) Hibernate: select webticket0_.TICKET_STATUS as col_0_0_,
>   count(webticket0_.TICKET_STATUS) as col_1_0_,
>   trunc(to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI
>   PM')-to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')) as col_2_0_
>   from ITS_TICKET_MASTER webticket0_ group by webticket0_.TICKET_STATUS
>   , trunc(to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI
>   PM')-to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM'))
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query 
>   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.handledNonSpecificException(ErrorCodeConverter.java:92)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.convert(ErrorCodeConverter.java:80)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1565)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1545)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:375)    at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
>   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:840)    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:74)    at
>   com.service.FetchFormService.fetchFormDetailsforAgeingReportDayWise(FetchFormService.java:170)
>   at
>   com.functionalService.FetchFormFunctionalService.fetchFormDetailsforAgeingReportDayWise(FetchFormFunctionalService.java:275)
>   at
>   com.actionClass.AgeingReportAction.fetchAgeingReport(AgeingReportAction.java:49)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:276)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:196)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)    at

I don't have any answer to this. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "*getTimestamp not implemented*" sounds like you have a **really** old (and thus outdated) JDBC driver version. Which version are you using (the number in the filename is **not** the driver version, it only indicates the *Java version* for which the driver is intended)

Answer (score 0):

(I was using Oracle driver 11.2 with 3.2.6.ga)

The problem seems to be the **0 as last_change_date_time** in my query
I replaced this with sysdate and it worked.

So perhaps you are trying to map a number on to a date as I did.
in your *(trunc (to_date('2004/12/14 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')-to_date('2004/12/12 4:29 PM', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI PM')) as days)* days should not map to a date

I got the same issue when I was doing this :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="myorg.tables.PtProfileData" table="PROFILE_DATA" >
        <composite-id name="id" class="org.openrap.tables.PtProfileDataId">
            <key-many-to-one name="ptVariableDefinition" class="org.openrap.tables.PtVariableDefinition">
                <column name="VARIABLE_ID" length="4" />
            </key-many-to-one>
            <key-property name="dateTime" type="java.util.Date">
                <column name="DATE_TIME" length="7" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="valueNumber" type="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <column name="VALUE_NUMBER" precision="22" scale="0">
                <comment>May be add VALUE_TEXT and VALUE_DATE later</comment>
            </column>
        </property>

    <sql-query name="PtProfileData.getprofile">
        <return alias="PROFILE_DATA" class="myorg.tables.PtProfileData"/>
<![CDATA[select variable_id,
trunc(date_time,':timeparam') as date_time,
sum(VALUE_NUMBER) as VALUE_NUMBER ,
**0 as last_change_date_time**
from PROFILE_DATA 
where VARIABLE_ID = :varid and DATE_TIME between :fromtime and :totime 
group by variable_id,trunc(date_time,':timeparam')
order by date_time]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```